# fontforge: how to generate a font with a non-zero number of glyphs from a .dfont?

Tags: fonts

I'm attempting to use the ["fontpatcher"](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/tree/develop/fontpatcher) that comes with [vim-powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) in order to add some glyphs to the [ProggySquare font](http://www.proggyfonts.com/index.php?menu=download) (`.dfont` version).  This script appears to just use [fontforge](http://fontforge.org/)'s internal libraries in order to get the job done.  I've installed fontforge from homebrew on my Mac (running 10.7).

Unfortunately, the result is a `.bdf` file that contains `CHARS 0`; it doesn't actually contain any glyphs.  If I open `ProggySquare.dfont` with the GUI version of fontforge then I can see all of the glyphs but they all have a faint red 'X' over them.  No matter how I fiddle with the Encoding menu or with the "File > Generate Fonts..." menu, I cannot eliminate the red 'X'es or create an output font file that has any glyphs in it.  Does anyone know precisely what those red 'X'es are indicating in this case, and (more importantly) how to remedy my situation?

As a workaround I was able to switch to the TTF version of the font, in which fontforge and `fontpatcher` are able to find glyphs.  Unfortunately that also seems to have some other sort of bug and generates glyphs that are too tall (and maybe too wide too?).  I'm not sure what's going on there, so bonus points if you can solve that too...